# Eslint - Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, eslint

Working in a React / Webpack project I started to have problems with the eslint library.

The eslint package is downloaded using npm and it's used to validate the project using a webpack preLoader.

```
        preLoaders: [{
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            loaders: [ 'eslint' ],
            include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app')
        }]
```

It used to work fine until recently when I tried to git clone the same project to an other folder. 
After installing the dependencies "npm install" and starting the project "npm start" the following error appeared.

```
    ERROR in ./main.view.jsx
Module build failed: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at keys (native)
    at Referencer.Visitor.visitChildren (project/node_modules/eslint/node_modules/escope/node_modules/esrecurse/esrecurse.js:78:24)
    at Referencer.Visitor.visit (project/node_modules/eslint/node_modules/escope/node_modules/esrecurse/esrecurse.js:112:14)
    at Referencer.Visitor.visitChildren (project/node_modules/eslint/node_modules/escope/node_modules/esrecurse/esrecurse.js:93:26)
    at Referencer.Visitor.visit (project/node_modules/eslint/node_modules/escope/node_modules/esrecurse/esrecurse.js:112:14)
    at Referencer.Visitor.visitChildren (project/node_modules/eslint/node_modules/escope/node_modules/esrecurse/esrecurse.js:93:26)
    at Referencer.Visitor.visit (project/node_modules/eslint/node_modules/escope/node_modules/esrecurse/esrecurse.js:112:14)
    at Referencer.Visitor.visitChildren (project/node_modules/eslint/node_modules/escope/node_modules/esrecurse/esrecurse.js:88:38)
    at Referencer.Visitor.visit (project/node_modules/eslint/node_modules/escope/node_modules/esrecurse/esrecurse.js:112:14)
    at Referencer.Visitor.visitChildren (project/node_modules/eslint/node_modules/escope/node_modules/esrecurse/esrecurse.js:93:26)
 @ ./app.jsx 17:26-57
```

The strange part of all is that the old project installation still works.

The problem must be somewhere in the node_modules folder because when I copy the modules from the old installation to the new one the project suddenly works.
I did a "npm list --depth=0" on both projects and both have the same packages and versions. Why one is working and the other one not?

I guess the problem is in the eslint package because when I remove the preLoader it works again.

I'm really confused about that. Someone had that problem before?

My main.view.jsx looks like that

```
import React from 'react';
export default class MainView extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div />
        );
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What about _/main.view.jsx_? Could you also show it?

Comment: @nAz I just updated the question with the main.view.jsx. As you will see is just an empty react component. I tried to isolate the environment as much as possible.

Comment: Updating eslint solved this issue for me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I could solve the problem by myself.

Isolating everything I found out that the problem was the babel dependencies.

For some reason the combination of versions I had of babel-core, babel-loader and babel-eslint where not working properly together.
I changed the babel versions required for my project in the package.json and now everything works fine.

```
-    "babel-core": "5.6.x",
-    "babel-loader": "5.3.x",
-    "babel-eslint": "3.1.x",
+    "babel-core": "5.8.x",
+    "babel-loader": "5.4.x",
+    "babel-eslint": "4.1.x",
```

Here my eslint dependencies

```
"eslint": "1.10.x",
"eslint-loader": "1.1.x",
"eslint-plugin-react": "3.10.x"
```

Hope the time I lost with that will help someone else!

Comment: It just did help someone else! :D

Comment: Hmm, I don't really understand why this is the chosen answer. This solution will soon be a non-viable solution. That is all :)

Comment: Still available. Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Looking through the thread https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/4485, the solution now is very simply to update babel-eslint to 4.1.6. For instance, "babel-eslint": "^4.1.6". Now works :)

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, I was able to fix this by just disabling a single rule:

Add this into your rules:

```
    'no-octal-escape': 0,
```

Answer (score -3):

if your code contains

```
export * from "."
```

remove above line

Comment: Even though this answer was graded -4, it DID HELP me find the cause to this problem. I was importing the "yup" npm package as `import * as Yup from 'yup'`, after removing asterisk and just importing the default `import Yup from 'yup'`, ESLint came back to life. So this answer is just inaccurate